# Click on Button to display image

Tags: java, android, image, button

I'm trying to create a simple android app, which has multiple buttons but just 1 imageView. Each button will have a unique image. It displays in the imageView when clicked on. Here is my java code:

```
public void poundedYamFunction(View view){

    ImageView swallowImage = (ImageView) view;
    swallowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.poundedyam);
}

public void ebaFunction(View view){

    ImageView swallowImage = (ImageView) view;
    swallowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.eba);
}

public void semoFunction(View view){

    ImageView swallowImage = (ImageView) view;
    swallowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.semo);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

As per the details and code , multiple buttons are associated with different views and the `View view` reference here is the reference to the `Buttons` not the imageview so you need to initialize the `imageView` reference and set the image accordingly.

like

```
ImageView img;

...oncreate(..){
    setContentView(..);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.id_of_image_view);
}

public void poundedYamFunction(View view){

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.poundedyam);
}

public void ebaFunction(View view){

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.eba);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pavneet, i followed this code but only the poundedYamFunction worked, the other buttons didnt change the image, it was just the image for the poundedYamFunction that showed

Comment: @Burburj make sure your other buttons pointing to different methods , or post your xml

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with below code. Implement activity with `View.OnClickListener` and on `onClick(View view)` change image.

```
    public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button button1, button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button_2);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {

            case R.id.button_1:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.poundedyam);
                break;

            case R.id.button_2:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.eba);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```